Native compilation of prebuilt .NET binary using ilc fails with "Main() has parameters, but the class library doesn't support them" error
I have a .NET binary which has to be compiled using .NET Aot after an obfuscation step over the original binary using Obfuscar.
As a reproducible example here's an example
public static class Program {
   public static Main(string[] args) {
      Console.WriteLine(args[1]);
      Console.WriteLine("test");
  }
}

and heres obfuscar.xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<Obfuscator>
  <Var name="InPath" value="." />
  <Var name="OutPath" value=".\Obfuscator_Output" />
  <Var name="KeepPublicApi" value="false" />
  <Var name="HidePrivateApi" value="true" />
  <Var name="RenameProperties" value="true" />
  <Var name="RenameEvents" value="true" />
  <Var name="RenameFields" value="true" />
  <Var name="UseUnicodeNames" value="true" />
  <Var name="HideStrings" value="true" />
  <Var name="OptimizeMethods" value="true" />
  <Var name="SuppressIldasm" value="true" />
  <Var name="InPath" value=".\bin\Release\" />
  <Var name="OutPath" value=".\obf\" />
  <Module file="$(InPath)net8.0-windows\win-x64\publish\BUILD.dll" />
</Obfuscator>

and here is a build script
@echo off
dotnet build -c Release
Obfuscar.console obfuscar.xml

now what I need is turn this dll file to an exe, first copying all dll files to the obf directory then running
ilc  -r ./ --systemmodule System.Private.CoreLib  "BUILD.dll" -o BUILD.exe 
which doesn't produce the binary
Error: One or more errors occurred. (Main() has parameters, but the class library doesn't support them)
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Main() has parameters, but the class library doesn't support them)
 ---> System.Exception: Main() has parameters, but the class library doesn't support them

and what I don't understand is how NativeAot originally builds executables, I need to replicate this setup but by through an obfuscation step.

You can compile a different project and look at the .rsp file in the obj directory so see what options go to Ilc.
